# jQuery replaceWith() not replace new value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simple html code with 2 button and script to replace element when click each button. When I click button 1 it replace right way as expected. But continue click button 2 it still replace old value which I have when click button 1.

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("button[name=btn-add]").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let Button_Id = $(this).attr("id")
    console.log(Button_Id);
    let test_content = $("#div-clone");
    stri = '<div>' + Button_Id + '</div>';
    test_content.find('#hello').replaceWith(Button_Id);
    test_content = test_content.html();
    console.log(test_content);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="btn-add" id="1">
  <i class="fas fa-plus fa-1x"></i> 
  <span style="padding-left:3px;"> button 1 </span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="btn-add" id="2">
  <i class="fas fa-plus fa-1x"></i> 
  <span style="padding-left:3px;"> button 2 </span>
</button>
<div name="div_test" id="div-clone" style="display:none">
  <span id="hello"> hello </span>
</div>
```

When click button 1 and then click button 2:

**result:**

> // 1  1
>   // 2  1

**expect:**

> // 1  1
>   // 2  2

Comment: The first click completely removes the `#hello` element, as you call `replaceWith()` on it, hence the second click behaves differently. What exactly are you trying to make this code do?

Comment: what I want is: when click button 1 it will replace content of `test_content` by id of button 1, after that click button 2 it will replace content of `test_content` by id of button 2.

Comment: In that case use `text()` instead of `replaceWith()`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find the element with the id of **'hello'** on the second click because its already been removed. But you can modify your code to add a new div with the sane id again. So you replace `<div id="hello">hello</div>` with `<div id="hello">1</div>` or `<div id="hello">2</div>` depending on the button id that you clicked:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("button[name=btn-add]").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let Button_Id = $(this).attr("id")
      console.log(Button_Id);
      let test_content = $("#div-clone");
      stri = '<div id="hello">' + Button_Id + '</div>';
      test_content.find('#hello').replaceWith(stri);
      test_content = test_content.text();
      console.log(test_content);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="btn-add" id="1">
  <i class="fas fa-plus fa-1x"></i> 
  <span style="padding-left:3px;"> button 1 </span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="btn-add" id="2">
  <i class="fas fa-plus fa-1x"></i> 
  <span style="padding-left:3px;"> button 2 </span>
</button>
<div name="div_test" id="div-clone" style="display:none">
  <span id="hello"> hello </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code was you were replacing the div, so basically when you click on the second time the "**hello**" div is not there instead of replacing you can change the text inside div like below

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("button[name=btn-add]").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let Button_Id = $(this).attr("id")
      $("#div-clone").find('#hello').text(Button_Id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="btn-add" id="1">
  <i class="fas fa-plus fa-1x"></i> 
  <span style="padding-left:3px;"> button 1 </span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="btn-add" id="2">
  <i class="fas fa-plus fa-1x"></i> 
  <span style="padding-left:3px;"> button 2 </span>
</button>
<div name="div_test" id="div-clone">
  <span id="hello"> hello </span>
</div>
```

**Note**

If you wanted to add the element you can use like below, so eventhough it replaces the next time when you are clicking we are replacing with a div of id "**hello**" so it will be able to find it out from the dom.

```
$("#div-clone").find('#hello').text('<div id="hello">' + Button_Id + '</div>');
```